# Can anyone give an example of server side implementation of OAuth 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, authentication

Can anyone give an example of server side implementation of OAuth 2.0? Basically im creating an API where the API users could authenticate them self and use apis same way we do on Facebook.  so need an OAuth server implementation for WCF REST service.

Comment: i have seen the client side usage but not how to implement server.

Comment: Its Ok to DisLike the question, but should give reason to dis like..

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work like _give me some example or code_. Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: I have implemented similar myself but I haven't shared code online because it is in my custom solution.
It is very hard to find already implemented solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search GitHub, there are lots of examples there.

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=oauth+server

You should do some research and work before posting questions like this here.